# behavior c3po and incorrect database ip

Tags: oracle, ip, c3p0

Good day!
I'm have a c3po setting that restore the connection to the database (Oracle 11g) when it is broken - it works

```
<properties>
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
      <!--property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/-->
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect" value="true"/>
      <!--максимальное количество соединений в пуле-->
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="10"/>
      <!--минимальный размер пула-->
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="3"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1"/>
      <!--как долго ждать, чтобы подтвердить соединение, т.е. не закрывать его, а, например, сделать запрос "select 1"-->
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="30"/>
      <!-- In seconds -->
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
      <!--таймаут для с3p0-->
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="0"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
      <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="50"/>
      <!--limits how long a client will wait for a Connection default 0 Setting any positive value will cause the getConnection() call to time-out and break with an SQLException after the specified number of milliseconds -->
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.checkoutTimeout" value="0"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery" value="select 1 from dual"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckIn" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts" value="0"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay" value="5000"/>
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="false"/>
    </properties>
```

But now I have found a mistake. If you do set incorrect ip database, the application just runs into the waiting. And we would like to give a reasonable answer. Help please.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://hibernatedb.blogspot.se/2009/05/c3p0properties.html);

```
c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts=3
#Default: 30
#Defines how many times c3p0 will try to acquire a new Connection
#from the database before giving up. If this value is less than or
#equal to zero, c3p0 will keep trying to fetch a Connection
#indefinitely.
```

Since you don't want to try indefinitely but return an error message, you should set this value to a value greater than 0. The default, 30, should be more than sufficient, if you can't reconnect a broken connection in 30 attempts, things are probably broken to the point where you want to let someone know about it.

Comment: Thanks again,еrouble with showing  error when ip incorrect resolved, but now new trouble. When c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts!=0 and connection broken (network broken) when program run - then app not reconnected to oracle...and not show any error.......

Comment: Hi all! I'm resolved my problem. Before jpa initialization i'm simple try create connection to oracle via jdbc, if connection success then close it and init jpa else throw exception. Thank all a lot for help

Answer (score 0):

I'm mistake what i no catch any exception. When i'm set acquireRetryAttempts=1 (for example), my app catch next exception:

1) When i'm remove network cable from computer before run application:

```
DBLogAppenderJPA::create() null
2453 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2] WARN  com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool  - com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@1d47b2b -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (1). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
 java.sql.SQLException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:412)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:221)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
Caused by: oracle.net.ns.NetException: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:359)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.resolveAndExecute(AddrResolution.java:422)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.establishConnection(NSProtocol.java:672)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:237)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1042)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:301)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:141)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnOption.connect(ConnOption.java:123)
    at oracle.net.nt.ConnStrategy.execute(ConnStrategy.java:337)
    ... 17 more
```

2) When i'm remove network cable from coputer when app is running and hibernate and conn pool is init.

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:92)
    at ru.sigmasoft.DoMessage.MessageProcessing.MessageBean.OracleMessageBean.OracleTableConsumer.listen(OracleTableConsumer.java:171)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1377)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1300)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:80)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:185)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:75)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to commit against JDBC connection
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:178)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: Connection reset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doCommit(T4CConnection.java:613)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:3674)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.commit(PhysicalConnection.java:3680)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection.commit(NewProxyConnection.java:803)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.doCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:112)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:168)
    at oracle.net.ns.Packet.receive(Packet.java:282)
    at oracle.net.ns.DataPacket.receive(DataPacket.java:103)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.getNextPacket(NetInputStream.java:230)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:175)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:100)
    at oracle.net.ns.NetInputStream.read(NetInputStream.java:85)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.readNextPacket(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:122)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.read(T4CSocketInputStreamWrapper.java:78)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalUB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1179)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CMAREngine.unmarshalSB1(T4CMAREngine.java:1155)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:279)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOCOMMIT(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:75)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doCommit(T4CConnection.java:558)
    ... 11 more
```

In both cases no connection recovery... But why?